# How to use environment variable in a view octobercms

Tags: octobercms

I ran php artisan october:env, I'm wondering how to use an environment variable in a view.

### For Example:

```
            <a href="/">
                <img src="{{'assets/img/logo-transparent-w.png'|theme}}" height="50" width="50" alt="Logo"/>
                <span>{{env(APP_NAME)}}</span>
            </a>
```

Answer (score 7):

So I was reluctant to answer this myself, but I figured out how to do it and thought it might help someone else. After running:

```
php artisan october:env
```

An .env file is created and some config/app.php files are changed to utilize the environment variables.

To actually use environment variables in the view I had to add them to the onStart() function at the beginning of the file. For example:

```
description = "Default layout"
==
<?php
function onStart() {
    $this['API_KEY'] = getenv('GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY');
} 
?>
==
```

Then in the view you can access the $this['API_KEY'] variable like this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{API_KEY}}&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
    async defer></script>
```

I hope this help anyone who runs into this.

Comment: Great, thank you so much! You might want to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a variable to check if the app is running in dev or production with `{{ this.environment }}` but thats about it.

You can always pass the `env()` results to the partial from the controller. I understand that this could be quite annoying if used for most partials.